# Passing React Refs in a Higher Order Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, dom-manipulation

I have a component architecture in which there is a Navigation component that contains several unique Navigation Button components. The Navigation Button components each contain a Nav Item component made of an A-tag and an I-tag.

It looks like:

> Navigation > Navigation Button > Nav Item > A-tag/I-tag

I'm tasked with implementing some DOM manipulation functionality and will need to access unique Refs placed on a Nav Item component's A-tag and I-tag.

The Refs on both the A-tag and the I-tag will need to be unique and relevant to their parent Navigation Button component.

Lastly, I will need to eventually store all of these Refs in an array-like structure and send them back to the top-level Navigation component for state management.

I've tried creating a ref at the Button Component level and passing it down as a prop to be placed on the A-tag and I-tag, but the value becomes null.

It seems that there are many situations in which Refs are overwritten and generating them dynamically is proving to be challenging.

**QUESTION** : Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can successfully give the Nav Item's A-tag and I-tag unique refs, which can later be stored in a data structure with Refs from other A-tags and I-tags, which will be used by the parent Navigation component?

Though I've simplified the code a lot, the general component architecture looks like this:

Several unique button components that look like:

```
class ButtonOne extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Some state stuff happens here
    this.buttonOneRef = React.createRef();
}


render(
    <Nav.Item 
        buttonRef = { this.buttonOneRef }
        />
);

    export default ButtonOne
}
```

---

A NavItem component that looks like

```
class NavItem extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Some state stuff happens here
}

const dropdownIcon = (
    <React.Fragment>
        <i ref={`${this.props.buttonRef}-${this.props.label}-i`/>
    </React.Fragment>
)

const link = (
    <React.Fragment>
        <a ref={`${this.props.buttonRef}-${this.props.label}-a`>{this.props.label}</a>
    </React.Fragment>
)
return (
    <li>
       {link}
       {dropdownIcon}
    </li>

export default NavItem
}
```

---

And a Navigation component that looks like

```
class Nav extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // Some state stuff happens here
    }

    render() {
        const childrenItems = React.Children.map(this.props.children), (child, index) => {
            return (
                React.cloneElement(iteem, {
                    // Some Props here
                })
            )
        }
    }

    return (
         <nav>
            <ul>
                {childrenItems}
            </ul>
        </nav >    
     )

    export default Nav
  }
```

Comment: I think you need to attach `buttonOneRef` to react element via the `ref` attribute in `ButtonOne` component. and if you want to forward this to nested component use `React.forwardRef`.

Comment: @AviatorX -- do you know what that syntax would look like?

Comment: hope this will help https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-in-higher-order-components